# function in case condition

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a kind of Tree:

```
public static final String CREATURES = "11";
public static final String NPC = "111";
public static final String PLAYER = "112";
public static final String OBJECTS = "12";
public static final String OBJECT = "121";
public static final String WEAPON = "1221";
public static final String SWORD = "12211";
public static final String BOW = "12213";
```

This is the Type class which hold the type number(identifier):

```
private String identifier;
public Type(String identifier){
    this.identifier = identifier;
}
```

And this is the function to check if `Type` isType of something:

```
public boolean isType(String otherIdentifier){
    if(this.identifier.length() < otherIdentifier.length()) return false;
    for(int i = 0; i < otherIdentifier.length(); ++i){
        if(otherIdentifier.charAt(i) != this.identifier.charAt(i)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
//identifier and otherIdentifier are the numbers for example 112 by Player
```

So `SWORD` is type of `WEAPON` and `OBJECTS` but not type of `NPC` for example.

Now I need to check which type it is:

```
public void doSomething(Type type){
    if(type.isType(Type.WEAPON)){
        //do something with weapon
    } else if(type.isType(Type.CREATURES)){
        //do something with Creature
    } ...
}
```

Now I wonder if I can do it with `switch` statement like:

```
switch(type){
    case .isType(WEAPON) : /* do something */ break;
    case .isType(CREATURES) : /* do something */ break;
    ...
}
```

Is this possible, or must I do it with if else statements?

Comment: I would recommend you to just use an `enum` instead. You are basically reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: @Ben `enum` is not a option in my case, but thanks.

Comment: You are replicating the functionality of an enum 1 to 1. Why wouldn't that be an option...

Comment: You can't see the whole program.

Comment: are you comparing two strings in `isType`? Just use `return identifier.equals(otherIdentifier)`. There is no need to compare characters by character in strings.

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc `eqauls()` doesn't work because the strings are not the same length `identifier = 1221 and otherIdentifier = 12` must return true but `equals()` will return false

Comment: @Morchul, oh I see, what about `String#startsWith` in this case? `identifier.startsWith(otherIdentifier)`

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc Yes this will work, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It only supports constant

You just need read the official doc at here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

> A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in Numbers and Strings).